# Get number of records in table

Tags: sqlite, html

I have following piece of code, which should be able to log to console number of records (if table `subjects` exists).

```
db = openDatabase("myDatabase", "1.0", "", 200000);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nor FROM subjects", [],
        function(result){
            console.log(result.rows);
        },
        function(tx, error){
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE subjects (id REAL UNIQUE, name TEXT)");
        }
    );
});
```

Actually the `result.rows` is logging as undefined, so i even cannot call method `item(int index)` on it. How can i get access to number of returned records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `tx` parameter in your onSuccess callback function.  Your `result` variable actually is the transaction object.

Here’s the corrected code:

```
db = openDatabase("myDatabase", "1.0", "", 200000);

db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nor FROM subjects", [],
        function(tx, result){ // <-- this is where you forgot tx
            console.log(result.rows);
        },
        function(tx, error){
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE subjects (id REAL UNIQUE, name TEXT)");
        }
    );
});
```